# Subreport source in Crystal Reports for .Net

Tags: .net, crystal-reports

I am using several sub-reports in a Crystal Reports solution in .Net. I created a stand-alone report, then imported that report into several other reports as a sub-report. Changes to the stand-alone version are not incorporated into any of the reports leveraging it. Will I need to continually re-import the report in this manner, or is there a way to have Crystal Reports for .Net reference another ".rpt" file so that changes are automatically applied?

EDIT: Now I see that right-clicking and choosing "re-import" actually has a problem associated with it. Namely, all of the subreport fields disappeared. Text headers and lines remained, but all of the fields disappeared. I even traced the SQL to make sure the linking was working as advertised, and then I tested the SQL to ensure that there was a result set being returned. The report simply "broke". I have to remove them and re-add them. What a pain.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this is the CR for .Net and cannot check now, the feature is in the full blown version.

right click the report on the main screen and bring up the format subreport properties select the option for "Re-import Subreport on Open".  The report will have to open on the main page for this to activate.

Comment: Yes, sorry; this is for Crystal Reports for .Net, integrated into VS 2005